# How to write a function in TypeScript that can query deep object and return the type of the nested key when called?

Tags: typescript

I have the following predefined object:

```
export const catalog = {
  category1: {
    newDomain: 'Hello'
  },
  category2: {
    otherStuff: 30
  }
};
```

Now I need to achieve two things:

- Get union of nested keys i.e. Union of `newDomain` and `otherStuff`
- A function that accepts two parameters - first is the valid category id (top level keys in the `catalog` object) and then second argument as the valid key under the selected category id and finally, return the value of the selected key.

It means I need a function `validate` such that:

```
const value1: string = validate('category1', 'newDomain');
const value2: number = validate('category2', 'otherStuff');
```

Any other combination for validate function should fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I forgot to answer the first part (getting the union of nested keys):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QM4B4AqA+KBeKTAbQGsIQB7AM0IF0BuAWACgXRIoA5NYCAEwDS5LFAgAPXgDs+qKACUIAYwoAnPugAKKipBWghIADTylq9Vp0Q9IA8aSSSkigHdJ2d-hZRYiFBhyiEhDSsgCWklRWhACMUAD8UAAUmLHiUjIx8VBklDQpUABcUJIQAG5WAJSFxWVWTKzMypKowFCKcMCIFADm+FAA3l5tHRDdqiDRRf01zgAiFAC2cOFFAOQAEhAICBSrUAC+hkPtvGMqIABMU1AUwAAWVgDKwEhUVEUAzAAMB0fM+-U2OBoNwWvwAMIdLrdAx9UG8QTCdgQajDTo7brYehQAD0OKgACISnNFstJASoAAfQm3B4qZ6vKgElhAA)

```ts
type Values<T> = T[keyof T];

type NestedKey<T extends Record<PropertyKey, Record<PropertyKey, unknown>>> =
  Values<T> extends infer T1 ? (T1 extends T1 ? keyof T1 : never) : never;

const catalog = {
  category1: { newDomain: 'Hello' },
  category2: { otherStuff: 30 },
};

type NestedCatalogKey = NestedKey<typeof catalog>; // "newDomain" | "otherStuff"
```

---

First, write a function to do it for any object that has object values, then [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) it:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABANwIYBsYBNVQKaIA8AsAFCKIBKANGRQNIAMieAHvmFgM6IAKATnAAOeflACe9PONrlE9AIwt2eTjwHDREqTLqIAKso7cqeCHH5ZCTaqfOXrC25QB8L2S4AU6RjoBc8oy26Ar+8k6IcABGAFYB+gCUAZSIAN56-HhQIPxI0TEA2j46ALpFodIlANxkAL5kZOZgXFCIELgYcADmiAC8aXrt+F0W4goBqYhgeADuACJwALaoMGABAOQAEnjo6HDriLWyFEN4I-ziAEwTkVAAFqIAytnAwAEAzMxHdTWkZKCQWAIFAYbC4PAAYQ6ex6JDkTCMqhMAGtpHBgIgJCJ0W1od1juFEWpEKjxDisXgcUNOl0CkwSh5vL5pAEbIgQmFFElMeJsRjqTC6YwyooSgM5JlsrkQZgcPgmTpghUZLioDSEr96n9SE0WjKQHglP00LLwVC1TDPOtTucxutbOtpvMliswOsNYgAPSexAtfirLqNBB6k0Gy59GVg-DmmlWm2jS72xDrOD3J4vYDuqpen1gECLKKiBo64OtUN4d4Rk1RyF4rpx8G2hRJlNp-jPECvLNegBUegoA8HQ+HI9HI4AfpOp9PJ2QAIL8Lr51Stcm8gjrABEqYe7Yzm4OMB4YFTiFQXC4MC6YFQUXQBCgcEQQlQ-FQiyyokiGIpyc3ToWZZVgPAA6TxLneAAWABWBJEB7T1i11MsMANSCq1BOVawtboG2GBMWwAl1Vm7T0+zkMdKKo6iZ1o+dF2XMBVx-dc-yIoCwAPRAjymU9z0va9b3vTEnxfN8P3wfhvx5EQ-x3dNO2AUDwKg2D4MQ7VdTge8QMtSZywictw1qD1vTSfVDQCTdtl2OBN1sIyPi+MggA)

```ts
function validate <
  R,
  K0 extends PropertyKey,
  K1 extends PropertyKey,
  T extends Record<K0, Record<K1, R>>,
>(l0Key: K0, l1Key: K1, obj: T): R {
  return obj[l0Key][l1Key];
}

const catalog = {
  category1: { newDomain: 'Hello' },
  category2: { otherStuff: 30 },
};

function validateCatalog <
  K0 extends keyof typeof catalog,
  K1 extends keyof typeof catalog[K0],
>(l0Key: K0, l1Key: K1): typeof catalog[K0][K1] {
  return validate(l0Key, l1Key, catalog);
}

const value1 = validateCatalog('category1', 'newDomain'); // string
const value2 = validateCatalog('category2', 'otherStuff'); // number

const value3 = validateCatalog('category1', 'otherStuff'); /*
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~
Argument of type '"otherStuff"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"newDomain"'.(2345) */

const value4 = validateCatalog('category2', 'newDomain'); /*
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~
Argument of type '"newDomain"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"otherStuff"'.(2345) */

console.log({ value1, value2 }); // { value1: "Hello", value2: 30 }
```